# group by in mongodb on array elements

Tags: mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb,

I have the dataset that has docs like the following:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("546fca4bbadc0f7939048d76"),
"name" : "kami",
"time" : "20141105230100",
"entity" : [ 
    1, 
    3, 
    4
],
"count" : 10
```

}

and imagine that there are 1000 of them, now I want to group them by entityid and return the sum of the count so for example after grouping them I will have something like this:

(entity) 1 : 100
         2 : 1000
         3 : 300

.
.
.

if entity was not an array I could easily do it this way:

```
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");
    DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$entity");
    groupFields.put("sum", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$count"));
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList( group);
    AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);
    for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

But now that I have entity as an array can I do that ? Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");
  DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$entity");
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$entity");
groupFields.put("sum", new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$count"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
```